# How to decode JWT using JWT-auth in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

Hello my issue is that I need to verify a JWT token coming from android and decode it to fetch the information in the payload but I can't seem to find a decode method in the JWT-Auth 0.5*, is there another way to decode the payload to get the data?

Comment: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/125 first google result

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
 use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth; //use this library
```

try this

```
 $token = JWTAuth::getToken();
 $apy = JWTAuth::getPayload($token)->toArray();
```

also you can get other info like this

```
   try {
        // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
        $token = JWTAuth::getToken();
        $apy = JWTAuth::getPayload($token)->toArray();
    } catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_expired'], 500);

    } catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_invalid'], 500);

    } catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_absent' => $e->getMessage()], 500);

    }
```