# How to parser Json result from base64_encode() in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, base64

I have written a php script to decode a value using base64_decode() function. I want to store the parse the result into different variable. How do I achieve this??

```
 $str = 'eyJ0eXAiO0IjoiNTAwMCIsInZhbGlkaXR5IjoiMzAifQjdubnmGHANidodnd';
 $msisdn_64 = base64_decode($msisdn);
 print_r($msisdn_64);
```

**NB:** For privacy sake the $str variable contains dummy value And this Does not use a token to decode

The code above outputs:

> {"typ":"JWT","alg":"HS256"}{"sub":"456564685455","service":"000","created":20010809,"account_name":"Acct","iss":"Acft","exp":false,"amount":"000","validity":"30"}}�.'���A˕X=·&|�L�0�"����

I tried something like this `$msisdn[1]->sub` , `$msisdn[0]->sub` , and `$msisdn->sub` to the value in the second object but its not working. Please help

Comment: The problem is that its acctually a base64 encoded string... what to decode it using base64 format and parser the data in it into different variables

Comment: `$msisdn_64` does not contain valid JSON. Not only does it appear that two or more JSON objects are smushed together, there's also trailing binary garbage. There's no out of the box way to parse that properly.

Comment: So i do i fix this please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decode JWT using JWT-auth in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48309645/how-to-decode-jwt-using-jwt-auth-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the json_decode function

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Example:

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

?>
```

Comment: Base64 decode please.....the format specified was base64 using JWT library.

Comment: @Andre Then use a JWT library to parse this…?!

Comment: Please recommend one

Comment: We don't recommend third party software here.

Comment: you saved my life from that hell :)) <3

Answer (score -1):

```
$str = 'eyJ0eXAiO0IjoiNTAwMCIsInZhbGlkaXR5IjoiMzAifQjdubnmGHANidodnd';
$msisdn_64 = base64_decode($msisdn);
print_r($msisdn_64);
```

Here you need to decode the string again like below.

```
$str = 'eyJ0eXAiO0IjoiNTAwMCIsInZhbGlkaXR5IjoiMzAifQjdubnmGHANidodnd';
$msisdn_64 = json_decode(base64_decode($msisdn),true);
print_r($msisdn_64);
```

remember to put the parameter `true` in json_decode() method, because it returns the result as an associative array.