# Laravel nested route without having parent parameter

Tags: php, laravel, model

I'm trying to work out how I can achieve this with Laravel route and controller.
I'm having 3 tables as below:

user

- id
- name

company

- id
- name

company_user

- id
- user_id
- company_id

So as you might have guessed I have the following models:

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    public function companies(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Company extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    public function users(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

The relationship is `ManyToMany` and it works all fine.

So I'm trying to achieve the following route:

```
Route::apiResource('company/user', CompanyUserController::class);
```

I know I can achieve such this by the following route easily:

```
Route::apiResource('company.user', CompanyUserController::class);
```

However what I need in my route is not to require to pass the company id as route parameter.

I want the company_id to be set automatically through payload from JWT token which I already have. So imagine we have `company_id` as 1 in JWT token payload and I want the user to go to this link:
GET `/company/user`
and controller would then list all users who belong to the `company_id` 1 which is grabbed from logged in user JWT token payload. I want the nested resource functionality without needing to pass the parent parameter in the route and instead grabbing it automatically from logged in user token.

I don't want the route to be like `/company/1/user`.

I hope someone could help me achieve such these. This also needs to apply to all other controller methods automatically as in show, store, update etc.

Thanks guys.

Comment: I dont know how you implement your JWT Token to include the company_id since there is no code shown. But **if** it is already in the JWT Token, you can decode them just like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48309695

Comment: Once you decode the jwt, you can then do your eloquent things to fetch your users

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Kenneth
However this does not answer my question. My question is not how to get company_id from JWT token. I know all that bit. I need to find a way that laravel route predefine the parameter in the resource route rather than requiring passing the parameter.

A resource route like this `/company/1/user` works fine but I want this route `/company/user` to work the same and always assume company_id is ` without requiring to pass that 1 every time in the url.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: If you really dont want to use JWT decode, use `/company/user` without the company_id in the route, then you can change the method to a `POST REQUEST` to the route. Create a `hidden form` with hidden input. Use javascript or jquery to addEventListener to button click, channge the value of hidden input to the company_id you want then do form.submit().

Comment: Dont know if it works but you can use cookie like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45207639

Comment: if the only company that user can see in `/company/user` is the company that the user joined, then you can just fetch the company id from the model..

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using `apiResources` for both company and user routes, define a [custom route group](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-groups) instead:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'company'], function(){
    Route::apiResource('user', CompanyUserController::class);
    ... Other company routes if you need ...
});
```

Now, in `CompanyUserController` you can read the correct company id from JWT Token and do your stuffs.

The `php artisan route:list` result:

```
  GET|HEAD        company/user
  POST            company/user
  GET|HEAD        company/user/{user}
  PUT|PATCH       company/user/{user}
  DELETE          company/user/{user}
```

Comment: That means I need to check and make sure the user belongs to the company manually on every method of controller or in the construct of the controller. I was hoping I could rely on Laravel bind methods to do this for me instead of me doing it manually. Thanks for your solution though @Legoraccio

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer my own question, I ended up doing this route:

`Route::apiResource('company/user', CompanyUserController::class);`
As @Legoraccio suggested.

Then I did the following in my `CompanyUserController` constructor to make sure I'm sanitising data before hitting the methods.

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $payload = auth()->payload();
        $companyId = $payload->get('companyId');
        // making sure the selected company exists
        try {
            $this->company = Company::where('id', $companyId)->firstOrFail();
        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $exception) {
            abort(Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND, "Unable to find company");
        }

        // making sure the logged in user is part of the selected company
        try {
            $this->company->users()->where('users.id', Auth::user()->id)->firstOrFail();
        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $exception) {
            abort(Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND, "You don't belong to this company.");
        }
    }
```